# CSS: Why do I get spacing underneath my border?

Tags: html, css

In [the following HTML snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/sk27bca9/), I'm getting a few extra pixels of spacing under the border of my 'bucket' div for some reason.

I've been wracking my head as to why, but can't figure out how to get rid of it. Can anyone help?

Thanks!!

```
    <style>
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            outline: 0;
            font-size: 100%;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            list-style: none;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            border-spacing: 0;
            border: none;
            font-family: "Segoe UI"
        }

        .pane {
            width: 260px;
            background-color: #666;
            color: #fff;
            font-size: 9px;
        }

        .fieldWell {
            height: 100%;
            overflow: auto;
        }

        .bucket {
            display: inline-block;
            padding: 4px 0;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
            color: #a6a6a6;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .bucket > .caption {
            float: left;
            width: 80px;
            padding-left: 12px;
            font-size: 9px;
        }

        .properties {
            float: right;
            min-height: 28px;
            width: 163px;
            margin-right: 12px;
            border: 1px dashed #666;
            border-radius: 4px;
            background-color: #4a4a4a;
        }

        .property {
            width: 157px;
            height: 22px;
            margin: 2px 0 2px 2px;
            padding-left: 4px;
            background: #333;
            border-radius: 4px;
            border: 1px solid #212121;
        }

        .property .caption {
            float: left;
            width: 100px;
            line-height: 21px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <article class="pane">
        <section class="fieldWell">
            <div>
                <div class="bucket">
                    <h1 class="caption">Foo</h1>
                    <div class="properties">
                        <div class="property">
                            <h2>
                                <span class="caption">Hello world</span>
                            </h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="property">
                            <h2>
                                <span class="caption">Hi there</span>
                            </h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </article>
</body>
```

Comment: Do u have to use 100% height on .fieldWell? https://jsfiddle.net/sk27bca9/1/

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. The real scenario is more complex, and the .fieldWell will contain multiple buckets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `float:left` instead of `display:inline-block` on the `.bucket` element CSS,

```
.bucket {
  float: left;
  padding: 4px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
  color: #a6a6a6;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Wow, brilliant! Thanks! Any idea why inline-block was resulting in the artifact?

Comment: Making it a `float` may cause issues for the parent element's layout.

Comment: Read this article https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Answer (score 1):

I think it's to do with `display: inline-block`. I bet using `display: block` instead and either avoiding `float`ed elements or using a clearfix would work.

**Demo without any floats**: https://jsfiddle.net/sk27bca9/5/

**Demo** using `block` and `.clearfix`: https://jsfiddle.net/sk27bca9/4/

Comment: You were totally right. Do you know why inline-block breaks it?

Comment: Not sure, but `inline-block` is the wrong tool for the job in general. I'd have to research further.

Answer (score 1):

```
.fieldWell {
height: 100%;
overflow: auto;
border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
}

.bucket {
display: inline-block;
padding: 4px 0px 0px 0px;
color: #a6a6a6;
width: 100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sk27bca9/3/

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `display:block;` and clear float.

CSS:

```
.bucket {
    display: block;
    padding: 4px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
    color: #a6a6a6;
    width: 100%;    
}
.bucket:after {
    content:"";
    clear:both;
    display:block;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GCu2D/712/